# 'ImportError: No module named <project_name>.settings' in smoke test

Tags: scrapy

1. `scrapy crawl <spider_name>` works fine in my project.
2. In a smoke test I crawl a private page and assert the items are as expected.
3. Things were fine until I finished a serious project refactor, which for the smoke test ends up setting an env var in `setUp()`, which in effect sets `os.environ['SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = '<project_name>.settings'`
4. After setting this env var, `scrapy crawl` complains that `'ImportError: No module named <project_name>.settings'`
5. `scrapy.cfg` settings are correct, every thing else except this smoke test works fine.
6. The problem goes away simply by `os.environ.pop('SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE')` before `os.sys('scrapy crawl <spider_name>')`, but this doesn't feel right.

So, please someone let me know whtat caused the problem and what is the proper way to fix it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the reason:

Before `scrapy crawl` scrapy executes `scrapy.utils.project.get_project_settings`, where `scrapy.utils.conf.init_env` is called if `os.environ['SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE']` is not set, where project main dir is added to `sys.path`.

By setting this env var, the copy of `sys.path` scrapy gets does not have the path for project main dir, so the import fails.

Popping out `os.environ['SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE']` will cause `init_env` to be called, thus `scrapy crawl` works as supposed. Another way to get around would be to set `os.environ['PYTHONPATH']` to project main dir path, which is where scrapy looks later for the path.

The approach I finally take is to modify scrapy, disable the check for `os.environ['SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE']`, and always execute `init_env`. The worst cost for this is that every time `scrapy crawl` executes, scrapy will look for the project main dir path once, which does not seem like much work to me.  And the path will not be added multiple times to `sys.path` because it is checked before appending.

That's about it, please let me know if I am mistaken somewhere, thanks!